# Magento doubles add to cart quantity with jquery

Tags: jquery, magento, magento-1.8

So we are having problems with a script in our custom theme.

The script adds the simple product to the cart directly from the category page. However it is duplicating the product quantity so two are added each time the customer clicks.

The html is

```
<a class="add-to-cart simple-product" rel="nofollow" href="<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product, array()) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to cart') ?></a>
```

and the script is

```
    $('a.add-to-cart.simple-product').live('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('div.popup').remove();
        $.fancybox.showActivity();
        $.post($(this).attr('href'), function(response) {
            $.fancybox.hideActivity();
            $('div.popup').remove();
            $('#header ul.menu > li:last').replaceWith($(response));
            initCartDrop();
            $('#header ul.menu > li:last a.my-cart').trigger('mouseenter');
        });
```

When I opened firebug to view what is happening I see a post command shortly followed by a get command to a url http://oursite.co.uk/checkout/cart/add/uenc/dsadadad/product/380/form_key/asasasas/

Can anyone help with why this is duplicating the quantity?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any js code that submits a form when clicking on the add to cart button? A link to your page might help (if available).

Comment: Thankyou @Marius I have updated the question with the javascript that adds the simple product to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

You know what, I tried using bind instead of live in jquery and this managed to fix the problem. The updated code is :-

```
$('a.add-to-cart.simple-product').bind('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('div.popup').remove();
            $.fancybox.showActivity();
            $.post($(this).attr('href'), function(response) {
                $.fancybox.hideActivity();
                $('div.popup').remove();
                $('#header ul.menu > li:last').replaceWith($(response));
                initCartDrop();
                $('#header ul.menu > li:last a.my-cart').trigger('mouseenter');
            });
```